# What is Top User update interval time?

Tags: support, reputation, top-users

I cannot find myself in the Stack Overflow reputation league. I have just got my reputation above 200 on Stack Overflow.

It is written in the *top user* page of StackOverflow that

> users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues

So basically

**When do users enter the reputation leagues once they reach 200 rep?**

If it takes some time like (2-3 hours or days or weeks), then it should be mentioned on the Top user page or some other page. Sorry if it is mentioned in somewhere, but to my knowledge I couldn't find such statement.

Comment: Well, basically they have weekly categories, monthly categories, so whenever they add a week or month (or entire set of accounts in a new week), they should add your account there.